# Plivo events not registering

Tags: angularjs, plivo

I created sample application using plivo websdk in angular js through which i can recieve call on web browser.
I initate the call using my node server which works perfectly fine.

when i integrated sample code with my project then it is connecting plivo but not not registering events so whenever call is triggered its not performing any task.

this is project integrated plivo logs.Events are not registered.It just stops after printing OS version and "Plivo client connected.." and ends.[image]

while in my sample app it prints the following logs.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am not able to figureout what i am missing becoz of which events are not getting registered,What can be the possible scenario.Can anyone please help.Thanks

Comment: Hi Charlie,can you help me with this issue. @http://stackoverflow.com/users/4731823/charlieplivo

Comment: @richard87 can you help?

Comment: can you explain what you mean here: "when i integrated sample code with my project then it is connecting plivo but not not registering events so whenever call is triggered its not performing any task."

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution,actually in sample app i was passing data like:

```
{
"plivo_sip_credentials":{
                            "username":"abc",
                            "password":"sdfg345"
                        }
}
```

but in actual application i did silly mistake and directly passing **Object.plivo_sip_credentials**
like:

```
{
   "username":"abc",
   "password":"sdfg345"
}
```

Coz of that it was connecting but not registring the events.